# Laplace Transform of Derivative DeltaDirac(t-1)

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

$\mathscr{L}\{\delta'(t-1)\}=F(s) $

Im having a hard time thinking this.

My first thought was doing 
$F(s) =e^{-s} s$

But when i do the inverse laplace transform of this i get

$f(t)= \delta'(t-1) Heaviside(t-1)$

Comment: How do you do the inverse Laplace transform?

Comment: Wolfram can do it for me. (Funny story, when i try to do the laplace transform there, it cant calculate it)

Comment: Strange result from WolframAlpha. The expression $\delta'(t-1) \, \theta(t-1),$ where $\theta$ is the Heaviside function, is not even well-defined as a distribution.

Comment: I also think that $\mathscr{L}\{\delta'(t-1)\}(s) = s e^{-s}.$

Comment: A word of recommendation: Avoid using $*$ for multiplication. There is an operation called [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) which is written using an asterisk, and that is common when working with Laplace and Fourier transforms.

Comment: Thanks, im still searching, but im starting to think its a mistake in the book. I have the differential equation $y'(t) -2y(t) = \delta ' (t-1)$. I have to use laplace transform to solve it, t between -infinit and +infinit

Comment: What does the book say?

Comment: And i also dont know why i dont have $y(0)$ value

Comment: Because $\delta'(t-1) |_{t=0} = 0.$

Comment: @md2perpe That is why I use $\star$ to denote convolution.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that the Laplace transform of $\delta'(t-1)$ is $s e^{-s}.$ Formally we have:
$$
\mathscr{L}\{\delta'(t-1)\}
= \int_0^\infty \delta'(t-1) \, e^{-st} \, dt \\
= \underbrace{\left[ \delta(t-1) \, e^{-st} \right]_0^\infty}_{=0} - \int_0^\infty \delta(t-1) \, (-s) e^{-st} \, dt \\
= s \int_0^\infty \delta(t-1) \, e^{-st} \, dt
= s e^{-s\cdot 1} = s e^{-s}
$$